# Aptana - Which is the shortcut key to add author info and other info

Tags: key, aptana, shortcut

Does anyone kow what is the shortcut key to add info in the module page such as copyright info, author info etc. Some day back, accidently I pressed some key and that appeared. But now I cant figure out how it came.